# How to send JWT over socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, jwt

I need to send JWT over socket to secure chat between users.

How secure is to send it like this:

On login from local storage:

```
socket.emit("jwt", {
   jwt: jwt
});
```

And on server side to recive and decode?

I found also this way:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/', {query: "token=" + localStorage.getItem('AccessToken')});
```

and to use middlware on server side, but problem with this is, it will just send token on connect and reconnect, but when user login in my app scoket not connect again, any help with this?

Comment: Have a look at [socketio-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt) if you haven't done so. Sending token in query string is not recommended due to increased possibility of leaks.

Comment: I tried to implement it but not working, with simple-jwt